# Transverse $S^1$ actions on mapping tori

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fibre-bundles, fibration, monodromy

Up until now I have thought that the existence of a transverse $\mathbb{S}^1$ action on a  symplectic mapping torus implies that the mapping torus is trivial. Unfortunately I also came up with a counter example to this, which I am not sure is correct. First I will recall the construction of the mapping torus: take the product an interval $I$ with the fiber $\mathcal{F}$ and "glue" the ends using an homeomorphism of $\mathcal{F}$, $f$, to get the mapping torus $M_f$.

$$M_f =\frac{(I \times \mathcal{F})}{(1,x)\sim (0,f(x))}$$

By a "transverse $\mathbb{S}^1$ action" I mean an $\mathbb{S}^1$ transverse to the fibers. At first I assumed the existence of such an action immediately implied that the mapping torus is trivial, but this seems not to be the case.

Take as the leaf a torus and glue the ends using the holonomy map $f\in GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ given by

$$f=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0  \\ \end{array} \right)$$

Let $(x,y)$ be the coordinates on the torus and denote the base coordinate by $t$. Increasing the $t$ coordinate at unit speed, we travel once around the base of the mapping torus and we find $(0,x,y)\mapsto(1,-y,x)$. This appears to be a transverse $\mathbb{S}^1$ action on a non-trivial mapping torus.

Any helpful points to relevant literature would also be most appreciated.

Comment: Forgetting symplectic for the moment, given any homeomorphism $f : \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}$ there is a transverse $S^1$ action on the mapping torus $M_f$ if and only if the isotopy class of $f$ has finite order in the mapping class group (if and only if some power of $f$ is isotopic to the identity; if and only if $f$ is isotopic to a finite order homeomorphism).

Comment: Dear @LeeMosher, thank you very much for your answer. Though i believe i could prove this myself without much difficulty, it would be most useful to me if I had a reference i could cite. Any idea where i could look for this?

Comment: I don't have any reference to cite. I guess I would regard it as an exercise in topology.

Comment: The Klein bottle might be an instructive example here.